# How to join several TDMS files into one TDMS file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to join a high number of TDMS files to have one final TDMS file with Python.

I used the package: 'from nptdms import TdmsFile, TdmsWriter', but I don't really get how to use the TdmsWriter function correctly.

Has someone an idea how to write a final TDMS file?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you have a look [into the docs](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: @albert  Thats what I have:

import glob, os

from nptdms import TdmsFile, TdmsWriter

# List all *_movie.tdms files of the dataset

for file in glob.glob(path_to_data + dataset + '*_movie.tdms'):
    print(os.path.basename(file))
    tdms_file = TdmsFile(file)

    with TdmsWriter(path_to_data + 'JoinedFile.tdms') as tdms_writer:
        tdms_writer.write_segment([])

Comment: Please add this code to your question to improve its quality and show what you have done so far. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further hints about asking a good question and making you helping easier. In addition, could you provide some sample files to make your problem reproducible? Where exactly are you stuck at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

First read each tdms file in turn, getting its root property and groups. Then read the channels within the groups.
Finally, open the Tdms_Writer with a path of the output file and in 'append' mode. This will create a new tdms file and append to it with each loop iteration.

```
    files = ['sample_1.tdms', 'sample_2.tdms', 'sample_3.tdms']
    for file in files:
        print('Reading %s ' % file)
        with TdmsFile.open(file) as tdms_file:
            original_file = TdmsFile(file)
            root_object = RootObject(original_file.properties)
            original_groups = original_file.groups()
            original_channels = [chan for group in original_groups for chan in group.channels()]

            with TdmsWriter("merged_files.tdms", mode='a') as tdms_writer:
                tdms_writer.write_segment([root_object] + original_groups + original_channels)
```